# Mysql select count on left join with condition not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I need to count number of records on left table, i read other questions and end up with this query but the condition on COUNT is ignored

```
SELECT  a.name, COUNT( f.status <> 'e' ) AS total               
FROM    album AS a LEFT JOIN photo AS f
        ON a.id = f.idalbum
WHERE   a.iduser = 4
GROUP   BY a.id
```

is MySQL 5 DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cant specify a condition inside COUNT statment.

try this

```
   SELECT  a.name, COUNT( f.status  ) AS total               
   FROM    album AS a LEFT JOIN photo AS f
    ON a.id = f.idalbum
   WHERE   a.iduser = 4 or f.status <> 'e'
   GROUP   BY a.id
```

Comment: adding condition in WHERE hide records that should return 0 ( with no records on left table )

Comment: then you need to change AND to OR statment if you want all records

Comment: you got what you need or ? if not try to give a fiddle example or sample data.

Comment: you welcome :) , i just tested it in sqlfiddle :) . good luck

Answer (score 1):

What if you do:

```
SELECT  a.name, COUNT( f.status ) AS total               
FROM    album AS a LEFT JOIN photo AS f
    ON a.id = f.idalbum
WHERE   a.iduser = 4 and f.status != 'e'
GROUP   BY a.id
```